# why is it saying there is an open 'head' tag when there isn't?

Tags: html, tags, head

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<head>
<title>temp</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="this.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
</body>
</html>
```

Do you see more than 1 opening head tag?  Because both firefox and the w3 markup validator claim I already have an open head tag before the first one I can see...

Comment: if you're trying to become valid, i'm pretty sure `<meta>` tags go in the head and you don't need the `/>` endings using the doctype you are. also - whats in this.js? could be changing the `<head>` or adding another one.

Comment: @Nile: An external JavaScript file will not affect the validity of the HTML source referencing it, and most markup validators examine the initial markup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `meta` tag must be in a `head` tag. If it isn't, the `head` tag will be implicitly opened.

Since your `meta` tag is before your `head` opening tag, the `head` tag is implicitly opened, the `meta` tag is inserted, and then you explicitly open `head`.

To fix this, move the `meta` tag to somewhere after you open `head` (but before you close it).

Comment: You're right, thanks.  Seems the error was misleading though!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the meta description tag inside the  element,
**search engines**, including Google, will not consider as meta description (or other meta tags) something 
outside the  element.
You need to have correct (X)HTML mark-up, and you need all your meta tags inside the  element.